# How can I subscribe and unsubscribe from individual firestore queries?

Tags: ngrx

I am trying to modify an effect I have made into letting me start and stop multiple firestore queries by using two actions. Currently the effect allows me to start and stop a single firestore query by listening for two separate actions in the effect. I simply use a switchMap to switch into an empty observable when there is a stop action. This works just fine.

```
@Effect()
startStopQuery$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(
    ActionTypes.START,
    ActionTypes.STOP
  ),
  switchMap(action => {
    if (action.type === ActionTypes.STOP) {
      return of([]);
    } else {
      return this.afs.collection('collection', ref => {
        return ref.where('field', '==', 'x');
      }).stateChanges();
    }
  }),
  mergeMap(actions => actions),
  map(action => {
    return {
      type: `[Collection] ${action.type}`,
      payload: { id: action.payload.doc.id, ...action.payload.doc.data() }
    };
  })
);
```

What I actually want to do is to have multiple queries ongoing that I can start and stop with those same two actions, but where it depends on the action payload. When I modified it everytime I performed a new query the last one stops working. I think it is because the `switchMap` operator switches away from my last query observable. This is the best I have come up with:

```
@Effect()
startStopQueryById$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(
    ActionTypes.START_BY_ID,
    ActionTypes.STOP_BY_ID
  ),
  switchMap(action => {
    if (action.type === ActionTypes.STOP_BY_ID) {
      return of([]);
    } else {
      return this.afs.collection('collection', ref => {
        return ref.where('field', '==', action.id);
      }).stateChanges();
    }
  }),
  mergeMap(actions => actions),
  map(action => {
    return {
      type: `[Collection] ${action.type}`,
      payload: { id: action.payload.doc.id, ...action.payload.doc.data() }
    };
  })
);
```

As I said, I think the issue is the `switchMap` operator. But that is also what I depended on to make the "stop" work in the first place. I cant seem to come up with another solution as I am not very well versed in the style yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution. I make an object that maps ID's to the firestore statechanges observables. On the start action I make the listener and adds it to the object. I make sure that it automatically unsubscribe by piping `takeUntil` with the corresponding stop action. It returns a `merge` of all the observables in the object and I silply do as before. I also have a seperate effect triggered by the stop action to remove the observable from the object. It looks like so:

```
queriesById: {[id: string]: Observable<DocumentChangeAction<Element>[]>} = {};
@Effect()
startQuery$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.START_BY_ID),
  switchMap(action => {
    this.queriesByPlay[action.pid] = this.afs.collection<Element>('requests', ref => {
      return ref.where('field', '==', action.id);
    }).stateChanges().pipe(
      takeUntil(
        this.actions$.pipe(
          ofType(ActionTypes.STOP_BY_ID),
          filter(cancelAction => action.id === cancelAction.id),
        )
      )
    );
    return merge(
      Object.values(this.queriesByPlay)
    );
  }),
  mergeMap(actions => actions),
  mergeMap(actions => actions),
  map(action => {
    return {
      type: `[Collection] ${action.type}`,
      payload: { id: action.payload.doc.id, ...action.payload.doc.data() }
    };
  })
);

Effect({dispatch: false})
stopQuery$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.STOP_BY_ID),
  map(action => delete this.queriesByPlay[action.id]),
);
```

This seems to work and have no problems except for being convoluted hard to understand.